# Является ли предложение ССП или СПП?

Tags: спп, ссп

> Но вот липы кончились; я прошел мимо дома с террасой и мезонином, и передо мною неожиданно развернулся вид на барский двор и широкий пруд с купальней, с толпой зеленых ив, с деревней на том берегу, с высокой узкой колокольней на которой горел крест, отражая в себе заходившее солнце.

Правильно ли я считаю, что это ССП?

Comment: А куда деть "на которой горел крест"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это предложение с разными видами связей: бессоюзной (*Но вот липы кончились; я прошел мимо дома*), союзной сочинительной (*я прошел мимо дома с террасой и мезонином, **и** передо мною неожиданно развернулся вид* ) и союзной подчинительной(*с толпой зеленых ив, с деревней на том берегу, с высокой узкой колокольней, **на которой** горел крест, отражая в себе заходившее солнце*).